# R CMD check in my computer and in CRAN auto check

Tags: r, cran

In my computer, R CMD check said `0 NOTE, 0 WARNING, 0 ERROR` and I submitted to CRAN. But, *cran auto check* said that there are errors, warnings and notes.
Why?

R is latest version 3.6.1 and I use --as-cran option. 
I geuss the reason relates the fact that my computer cannot create pdf manual by the code `R CMD Rd2pdf pkg path` and thus the Latex check for Rd files is not incomplete.
So, I have submitted to CRAN in 20~30 times to use `R CMD check` of CRAN ...

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421013/cran-package-submission-r-cmd-checks)

---

The following error occurred in my R CMD check, but in the CRAN check, it did not occur and all my submission went through the CRAN check even if the following error did exist in my computer R CMD check.

```
* checking for file 'mypackage/DESCRIPTION' ... ERROR
Required field missing or empty:
  'Author'
```

I am not sure but the above error always occurs when I run R CMD check from comand line. But I could submit to CRAN even if R CMD check fails from comand prompt. 
And such error did not occurs in CRAN auto check or from Rstudio `devtool::check()`.

---

I cannot replicate the result of CRAN auto check.
I tried `R CMD check --as-cran` but it did not affects the result.

### I am not sure but devtools::check() is `--as-cran` by default and I use it always.

```
Type: Package
Title:  title
Version: 0.2.0
AUthor: first last
Authors@R: person(given = "first",family = "last",email = "xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", role = c("aut", "cre") )
```

### I added the AUthor: field but the error occurred.

My R was latest version, and further I use --as-cran but I cannot replicate the error of CRAN auto check.

---

```
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... NOTE
Author field differs from that derived from Authors@R
  Author:    'xxxx yyyyy'
  Authors@R: 'xxxx yyyyy[aut, cre]'
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, you get a transcript with those error, warnings and notes. That should give you some more information.

Comment: Do you run `R CMD check` on the tar.gz file built by `R CMD build`, or directly on the package directory?

Comment: No, I did not know the command `R CMD build`.

Comment: Well, so I think this is definitely the problem. ;) See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible explanations:

1. You are not using the same version of R. (For CRAN submissions, `R CMD check` should be performed with the latest version of R-devel.)
2. You did not add the option `--as-cran` when you checked your package. For CRAN submissions, you should do `R CMD check mypackage --as-cran`: more tests are performed than in the "standard" way.

To avoid those problems, you can check your package online with [Winbuilder](https://win-builder.r-project.org/) for example (although this is slightly less "eco-friendly" ;-)).

--

After your edit, I add this info:

In your `DESCRIPTION` file, you can use a simple `Author` field (which is the standard way), or you can use a more modern `Authors@R: c(person(...))` syntax (and I suppose that you've done that). If you do that, the `Author` field is missing, and `R CMD check` complains about that. Consequently, you should first build your package with `R CMD build mypackage`, and in a second step, check the tar.gz created, by running `R CMD check mypackage.tar.gz --as-cran`.

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. My R version was latest 3.6.1 and I run `R CMD check` with the option `--as@cran`. However, I cannot replicate the error of CRAN auto check. I also tried `R CMD build` but I cannot find where the `pkg.tar.gz` file  is created. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I can do the `R CMD build package path` and `R CMD check package.tar.gz path` but the result of R CMD check differs to CRAN auto check.